# How I import class module in concurrent.futures ProcessPoolExecutor map?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, biopython, multiprocess

I try to get sequence alignment score using processpoolexecutor in concurrent.futures module. But I have an error below.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from Bio import Align

def main():
    aligner = Align.PairwiseAligner()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        result = list(executor.map(aligner.align, ['fasd', 'fdas'], ['gdfs', 'fdsa']))
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I got a TypeError.
Error is

```
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bion/.conda/envs/project_env/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 208, in _sendback_result
    result_queue.put(_ResultItem(work_id, result=result,
  File "/home/bion/.conda/envs/project_env/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 372, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/home/bion/.conda/envs/project_env/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'Path generator' object
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bion/playground/notebooks/multiprocessing_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/bion/playground/notebooks/multiprocessing_test.py", line 8, in main
    result = list(executor.map(aligner.align, ['fasd', 'fdas'], ['gdfs', 'fdsa']))
  File "/home/bion/.conda/envs/project_env/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 559, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
    for element in iterable:
  File "/home/bion/.conda/envs/project_env/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 609, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "/home/bion/.conda/envs/project_env/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 446, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/home/bion/.conda/envs/project_env/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
TypeError: cannot pickle 'Path generator' object
```

I think This issue is that imported class not function. Do you have any idea?

I imported function. It works

```
def foo(a, b):
    return a+b


with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result = list(executor.map(foo, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]))
print(result)
```

my code flow is this

```
seqA = 'asdf'
seqB = 'asgf'

seq_length = min(len(seqA), len(seqB))
alignments = aligner.align(seqA, seqB)
similarity_score = alignments[0].score / (seq_length * aligner.match_score)
```

and I want to run many number of seqA and seqB
sequences_A = ['adf', 'agsdaf',...]
sequences_B = ['gafs,', 'asgdasdf', 'afasdf',...]

Comment: You code cause an instance of `Align.PairwiseAligner` to be passed to a subprocess which requires being able to pickle and unpickle them. There are several possible workarounds, but it's not possible to describe them in a comment and a deeper understanding of what the `Bio.Align.PairwiseAligner` class is and does.

Comment: Thank you :) I understand it. I add code below post. I want to run a lot of number of seqA and seqB.

Comment: A common workaround is to create the instance of the class *inside* each subprocess instead of trying to use a single instance that's shared by all processes. That sounds like it might work in this case.

Comment: Oh, I've got it. I solved the problem. Thanks a lot :)